# Cannot import an FBX model that I downloaded from Unity

Tags: import, unity, error, .fbx

I am completely new to Blender so it is possible I have missed a simple step so bear with me.

I downloaded a character asset from Unity but the rotation for the mesh collider is different to the actual model. So I downloaded Blender 2.91.0, planning on adjusting it there as I can't do it in Unity (I don't think) but when I try to import the FBX model, I receive this message

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py", line 216, in execute
    if import_fbx.load(self, context, filepath=path, **keywords) == {'FINISHED'}:
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2613, in load
    _(); del _
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2612, in _
    fbx_item[1] = blen_read_material(fbx_tmpl, fbx_obj, settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 1473, in blen_read_material
    blen_read_custom_properties(fbx_obj, ma, settings)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 372, in blen_read_custom_properties
    assert(val >= 0 and val < len(enum_items))
AssertionError

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: which model did you try to import? so that i can try and replicate the error
and by the way you can edit models in unity with a free package you might want to look into that

Comment: Here is the link: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/animals/toon-fox-183005

Comment: seems to be a bug i googled it and sadly there isn't a real fix - you can try to change in a different software - as i said check out model editing in unity. and also if it is a separate object you can rotate objects in unity